# Dependencies missing when NUnit executes MVC controllers unit tests on .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, nunit

I have two projects and the both are developed in .Net 6.
The first one is a kind of REST API and contains MVC controllers.
The second one is a NUnit project that contains unit tests of the MVC controllers of the first project.
When I execute my unit tests on Visual Studio (with ReSharper), everything is working well.
But when I try to execute those unit tests on the CMD with Cake, I got this error.

```
Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
  ----> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
  ----> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Which says that one dependency is missing.

The first thing I tried is to add the missing dependency with NuGet.
But I cannot add the missing dependency via NuGet to my test project because the missing dependency is only available on .Net Framework 4.5.1 and higher (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Abstractions/6.0.0-rc1-final). And the dependency that I can install, is not the requested one (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions/2.2.0).
I also try to change the project type inside my .csproj from `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` to `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` but it didn't worked.
I also try to add different package references like `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="7.0.0" />` and `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing" Version="6.0.13" />` but it didn't worked too.
I see that it is possible to create integration tests with xunit but I don't want to make integration tests and I want to keep NUnit (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0).
The only workaround that I found and which is working; it's to download the missing dependency as a DLL on the NuGet website and add them to the project references (https://nuget.info/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Abstractions/6.0.0-rc1-final). But I was wondering if there was a proper way. Maybe a NUnit configuration or something like that that I'm missing.
Have you experienced this problem before and know what I could do to fix this?

Thanks in advance